# Adding cordova bluetooth to meteor project

Tags: cordova, meteor, bluetooth, ionic-framework

I'm going to develop an cross platform app. I'm using meteor, cordova and ionic technology, but I'm having problems to add bluetooth plugin to my project, i googled for answers but I didn't find something useful.

Has anyone work with this platforms and used bluetooth, know who to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried ```255kb:cordova-bluetooth-state``` ?

Comment: The question is to add it with meteor add [comand]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I run these commands:

meteor add cordova:cordava-plugin-bluetooth-serial@0.4.4

And that work for me.